# Network access to windows service

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have problem with creating service that has access to files on network disk.

Service must have admin rights and it will be run by users that don't have admin privileges.

I send path as `UNC`
and file is seen by service but it return `ACCES_DENIED` errors when try to open or do anything on Network drive.

When I run my service as server , everything works fine.

I try to find answer but everywhere I can found only partial answers that do not help me at all.

========

I read that standard service logged as SYSTEM can't have access to network.
So i tried to log id as

1. `NetworkService`, `LocalService`
   It didn't work. After run it as one of those user my service can't save files on c:
2. Some kind of admin account.But I didn't manage to success on that.
3. Actually logged user.
   I don't know how to get password for current user.
   Still this will not work for user without admin rights.

========

Please tell me what can I do?
There are plenty of Services that use somehow network resources. How do they do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure your service to run as a user which has sufficient rights. In this case you are looking for rights to network shares. Typically that's going to need a domain user with appropriate rights. Normally you'd ask your network manager to create a dedicated user account for the purpose.

You appear to be labouring under some false information as to how services work. You talk about running the service under the account of the logged on user. Remember that services run when there are no users logged on. And remember that there may be multiple logged users at any point in time.

Comment: Thx for anwser.
When i create service i specify acount for which it should be running.
So only think i need is to have acces to network drive and have admin rights.
When i run it under NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService i have access to network but i don't have access to f.e c:/Program Files so i assume this user don't have admin rights.

So is only way is to create separate admin account specify for this service?

Comment: I think so. That's certainly the best solution. In fact on my network, `NetworkService` can't see any of the network shares.

Comment: To be weirder.
When I run it on Win7 it works even on SYSTEM account(it have network access).
It have access_denied only on WinXp on which unfortunately it needs also to works.

I think,
is it possible to do not create entire new account for this specific service but to use account that install service.(we know it will have all privileges we need)
If yes, how can I pass to CreateService function credentials of current active user. Because obviously it can have different names and passwords. So it must be some generic way to do this?

Comment: The final parameter to `CreateService` is the password. Unless you know it, you'll have to ask the user to supply it when they are installing.

Comment: Do you know by any chance how antivir's do that that they work as service as admin, do not create any other account, do not ask for any password, and can access any location.?

Comment: My one scans locally. A component on the server scans the shares.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the port was getting blocked through firewall, I had to add a inbound rule and specify the port which i was using in my application. This way firewall did not blocked my port for outgoing connections.

References:

https://www.firehousesoftware.com/webhelp/FH/Content/FHEnterprise/FHEnterpriseInstallationGuide/24_StaticPort.htm